# What happens if two parties have the same public key?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, asymmetric

What would happen if I get a public key that someone else already has? Isn't the security very weak in that case?

Comment: -1 Can you explain about the specific case? your question is vague.

Comment: Everyone has the public key - it's "public" - everyone is *supposed* to have it

Comment: I understand the question to mean "what would happend if I generate a private-public key pair, and someone else already uses the public key as his public key". Would appreciate if OP could clarify.

Answer (score 3):

If you use a public key that someone else is using, it means that you are also using the same private key. In other words, that person would be able to (a) decrypt any encrypted messages you receive and (b) impersonate your digital signature. Just like a pair of identical house keys are interchangeable, a pair of identical public-private key pairs are interchangeable. That is bad.

But, still, you need not worry.

Why? As long as you generate your keys with a (pseudo) random algorithm, the chance of this ever happening is extremely small. The key space for a 1024 bit RSA key is primes all between `2^1023`and `2^1024`. According to [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/25083) there should be about `10^80` possible keys. That is about as many [as there are atoms in the universe](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/47941/dumbed-down-explanation-how-scientists-know-the-number-of-atoms-in-the-universe).

The chance at picking the same key as somebody else at random is therefore extremely small. If you want to do calculations for yourself, you can use [this formula](http://preshing.com/20110504/hash-collision-probabilities/), but the numbers will be so small their size is of no practical relevance.

**EDIT:** See Matthews comment for some relevant practical considerations.

Comment: This does assume that the algorithm is correctly seeded. See https://www.debian.org/security/2008/dsa-1571 for an example of what happens if the seed is weak. Similarly, if using pre-generated VM images or similar, it is important to generate your own keys, rather than using any that might exist on the system already, since pre-existing ones will be the same for every instance of the image.